# Debugging MVC app with EEF and heavy jquery implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging

I am working with a new project which is really complex and is written with MVC 1.0 and heavy jQuery implemenation. Since there is not a lot of documentation it is almost impossible to trace the flow of commands in the entire application. So I am trying to debug it and learn the implementation, but with jquery implementaion, it gets harder to understand the flow of commands and which function is called at what moment.

I was wonderng if there is a method to find out where the cursor is in the code at any given moment in time? Step into amd breakpoints has not been working for me that great. Is there any other tricks I might not be aware of to debug a MCV app?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Debugging an ASP.NET MVC application is no different from debugging an ASP.NET Web Forms application. But the client-side debugging will certainly most easily be done in a specialized JavaScript debugger, like the one built into Chrome.

Comment: Dude, that's just wrong. Also, "like" in my previous comment means "such as". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

- *Pause* your debugging session
  anytime.
- Select the correct thread (using the 'Thread' dropdown)
- Use *Show next statement*

Comment: Thanks for sharing the trick. But when I click Show next statement, nothing is happening. I am just noob.